# `noexcept` behavior of `constexpr` functions

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, constexpr, noexcept

The wording of **[expr.unary.noexcept]** changed in **C++17**.

---

Previously ([n4140, 5.3.7 noexcept operator [expr.unary.noexcept]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.unary.noexcept)), *my emphasis*:

> 3. The result of the noexcept operator is false if in a potentially-evaluated context the expression would contain
>
>    > (3.1) a potentially-evaluated call to a function, member function,
>    >     function pointer, or member function pointer that does not have a
>    >     non-throwing exception-specification ([except.spec]), **unless the call
>    >     is a constant expression ([expr.const])** ...

---

Now<sup>1</sup> ([7.6.2.6 noexcept operator [expr.unary.noexcept]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.noexcept)):

> 3. The result of the noexcept operator is *true* unless the expression is potentially-throwing ([except.spec]).

And then in [14.5 Exception specifications [except.spec]](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec):

> 3. If a declaration of a function does not have a noexcept-specifier, the declaration has a potentially throwing exception specification unless ...

but the *unless list* of 14.5(3) doesn't list `constexpr`, leaving it as potentially throwing...

<sub><sup>1</sup> a link to C++17 [n4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/except.spec#6) added by L.F. in a comment.</sub>

---

### Test code

```
constexpr int f(int i) { return i; }

std::cout << boolalpha << noexcept(f(7)) << std::endl;
int a = 7;
std::cout << boolalpha << noexcept(f(a)) << std::endl;
```

used to print ([with gcc 8.3](https://godbolt.org/z/ivAnRa)):

```
true
false
```

both when compiled with **-std=c++11** and **-std=c++2a**

---

**However** the same code prints now ([with gcc 9.2](https://godbolt.org/z/GWUEdg)):

```
false
false
```

both when compiled with **-std=c++11** and **-std=c++2a**

---

Clang by the way is very consistent, [since 3.4.1](https://godbolt.org/z/UsBDok) and goes with:

```
false
false
```

---

- **What is the right behavior per each spec?**
- Was there a real change in the spec? If so, what is the reason for this change?
- If there is a change in the spec that affects or contradicts past behavior, would it be a common practice to *emphasize* that change and its implications? If the change is *not emphasized* can it imply that it might be an *oversight*?
- If this is a real intended change, was it considered a bug fix that should go back to previous versions of the spec, are compilers right with aligning the new behavior retroactively to C++11?

---

<sub>**Side Note:** the `noexcept` deduction on a `constexpr` function **affects [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35110453/2085626)**.</sub>

Comment: The new rule is in C++17: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/except.spec#6.  I remember that there is an issue for removing the special rule for constant expressions.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47538175/2085626 which also has relevant discussion in the comments

Comment: Found a related question from 2016: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555793/does-constexpr-imply-noexcept

Comment: Here's a related bugreport for MSVC: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/implicit-noexcept-declaration-wrong-in-c/1389552

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Summary

> What is the right behavior per each spec?

`true false` before C++17, `false false` since C++17.

> Was there a real change in the spec? If so, what is the reason for this change?

Yes.  See the quote from the Clang bug report below.

> If there is a change in the spec that affects or contradicts past
>   behavior, would it be a common practice to emphasize that change and
>   its implications? If the change is not emphasized can it imply that it
>   might be an oversight?

Yes; yes (but CWG found a reason to justify the oversight later, so it was kept as-is).

> If this is a real intended change, was it considered a bug fix that
>   should go back to previous versions of the spec, are compilers right
>   with aligning the new behavior retroactively to C++11?

I'm not sure.  See the quote from the Clang bug report below.

## Detail

I have searched many places, and so far the closest thing I can find is the comments on relevant bug reports:

- [GCC Bug 87603 - [C++17] noexcept isn't special cased for constant expressions anymore](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87603)

  > CWG 1129 (which ended up in C++11) added a special case to `noexcept`
  >   for constant expressions, so that:
  >
  > ```
  > constexpr void f() {} static_assert(noexcept(f()));
  > ```
  >
  > CWG 1351 (which ended up in C++14) changed the wording significantly,
  >   but the special case remained, in a different form.
  >
  > P0003R5 (which ended up in C++17) changed the wording again, but the
  >   special case was removed (by accident), so now:
  >
  > ```
  > constexpr void f() {} static_assert(!noexcept(f()));
  > ```
  >
  > **According to Richard Smith in LLVM 15481, CWG discussed this but decided to keep the behavior as-is.** Currently, clang does the right
  >   thing for C++17 (and fails for C++14 and C++11, on purpose). g++,
  >   however, implemented the special case for C++11 already, but not the
  >   change for C++17. Currently, icc and msvc seem to behave like g++.
- [Clang Bug 15481 - noexcept should check whether the expression is a constant expression](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15481)

  > **The constant expression special case was removed -- apparently by accident -- by wg21.link/p0003. I'm investigating whether it's going
  >   to stay gone or not.**
  >
  > Did you do anything to avoid quadratic runtime on deeply-nested
  >   expressions?
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > **Conclusion from CWG discussion: we're going to keep this as-is. `noexcept` has no special rule for constant expressions.**
  >
  > **It turns out this is actually essential for proper library
  >   functionality: e.g., if `noexcept` tries evaluating its operand, then
  >   (for example) `is_nothrow_swappable` is broken by making `std::swap`
  >   `constexpr`, because `std::swap<T>` then often ends up getting
  >   instantiated before `T` is complete.**
  >
  > As a result of that, I'm also going to consider this change as an
  >   effective DR against C++11 and C++14... but I'm open to reconsidering
  >   if we see many user complaints.

In other words, the special rule was accidentally removed by [P0003](https://wg21.link/p0003), but CWG decided to keep the removal.