# C++ constexpr - Value can be evaluated at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was reading about `constexpr` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

> The `constexpr` specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time.

When I first read this sentence, it made perfect sense to me. However, recently I've come across some code that completely threw me off.  I've reconstructed a simple example below:

```
#include <iostream>

void MysteryFunction(int *p);

constexpr int PlusOne(int input) {
  return input + 1;
}

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  MysteryFunction(&i);
  std::cout << PlusOne(i) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Looking at this code, there is no way for me to say what the result of `PlusOne(i)` should be, however it actually compiles! (Of course linking will fail, but `g++ -std=c++11 -c` succeeds without error.)

What would be the correct interpretation of "possible to evaluate the value of the function at compile time"?

Comment: If you pass a non-constexpr argument to the `PlusOne` function, the compiler *can't* evaluate it at compile-time, and it will simply be a normal run-time function.

Comment: Hint: "The `constexpr` specifier declares that it is **possible** to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time."

Comment: Of course "can be" does not mean "will be", but the problem here is that "possible" does not mean "can be".  It seems like quite poor wording in my opinion.

Comment: *can be* != *will be* or *must be*. It just means *if* it can be evaluated at compile time the compiler will try to do that and you can try to use this in other `constexpr` contexts and if it *is* in fact a constant expression and that other thing *also* is. Then the whole thing *may* be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: FWIW, cppreference is not an "official description" of C++. It's a community-managed wiki, albeit a high-quality wiki. The language in cppreference is intentionally made more casual than the standard itself. Don't treat cppreference's statements as binding; if you want to be a language lawyer, refer to the standard itself (I like this website: http://eel.is/c++draft/)

Comment: Also we can have code not allowed in [constant expression context as long as we have one argument value that allows us to invoke the function in a constant expression context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34280783/1708801)

Comment: I'm not trying to be a language lawyer, I'm just here to understand the functionality.

Comment: @Apollys Sadly, in C++ nowadays, the two are often not separable :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The quoted wording is a little misleading in a sense. If you just take `PlusOne` in isolation, and observe its logic, and assume that the inputs are known at compile-time, then the calculations therein can also be performed at compile-time. Slapping the `constexpr` keyword on it ensures that we maintain this lovely state and everything's fine.

But if the input *isn't* known at compile-time then it's still just a normal function and will be called at runtime.

So the `constexpr` is a property of the function ("possible to evaluate at compile time" *for some input*, not *for all input*) not of your function/input combination in this specific case (so not *for this particular input* either).

It's a bit like how a function could take a `const int&` but that doesn't mean the original object *had* to be `const`. Here, similarly, `constexpr` adds constraints onto the function, without adding constraints onto the function's input.

Admittedly it's all a giant, confusing, nebulous mess (C++! Yay!). Just remember, your code *describes the meaning of a program*! It's not a direct recipe for machine instructions at different phases of compilation.

(To really enforce this you'd have the integer be a template argument.)

Comment: This answer is clearly correct.  I would just add that if you add `constexpr` to a variable it is enforced compile time.  So

<code>
  constexpr auto j = PlusOne(i); // main.cpp:13:31: error: the value of 'i' is not usable in a constant expression
  constexpr auto j = PlusOne(5); // OK
</code>

Answer (score 12):

A `constexpr` function *may* be called within a constant expression, provided that the other requirements for the evaluation of the constant expression are met. It may also be called within an expression that is not a constant expression, in which case it behaves the same as if it had not been declared with `constexpr`. As the code in your question demonstrates, the result of calling a `constexpr` function is not *automatically* a constant expression.

Comment: That makes more sense, that's kind of what I was guessing but it didn't seem to me like that was the literal interpretation of the sentence I quoted.

Answer (score 8):

> What would be the correct interpretation of "possible to evaluate the value of the function at compile time"?

If all the arguments to the function are evaluatable at compile time, then the return value of the function can be evaluated at compile time.

However, if the values of the arguments to the function are known only at run time, then the retun value of the function can only be evaluated at run time.

Hence, it *possible to evaluate the value of the function at compile time* but it is not a requirement.

Comment: Thank you, the official description seems incompletely/poorly worded in my opinion.

Comment: @Apollys, That's not the worst of it :) See the [actual standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.const) and you would know what I mean. That's why we need language lawyers.

Answer (score 4):

All the answers are correct, but I want to give one short example that I use to explain how ridiculously unintuitive constexpr is.

```
#include <cstdlib>
constexpr int fun(int i){
    if (i==42){
        return 47;
    } else {
        return rand();
    }
}

int main()
{ 
    int arr[fun(42)];
}
```

As a side note:
some people find constexpr status unsatisfying so they proposed [constexpr!](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1073r0.html) keyword addition to the language.

Comment: As an addendum, in case anyone comes by here later -- `constexpr!` has been accepted, but under the alternate name of `consteval`. :) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1073r3.html https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval