# assert in constexpr function

Tags: c++, constexpr

In trying to work out why I was getting a certain compile error, I came up with the following minimal example:

```
constexpr void Test(bool test)
{
    if (test)
        return;

    assert(false);
}
```

This compiles without issue with every version of clang I tried (3.7+), but fails with gcc (tested 5-8), with

> error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘void __assert_fail(const
>   char*, const char*, unsigned int, const char*)’

From my understanding, the function should be able to be `constexpr` because there is a set of argument values for which the function can be evaluated at compile time.

Is my understanding wrong, or is gcc incorrect in failing to compile this?

Comment: happens in gcc 7.2.0 too. Maybe gcc *is* wrong here ...

Comment: Similar to [Throw in constexpr function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34280729/1708801) bugs there are [part of gcc constexpr metabug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55004)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [GCC bug 86678](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86678), and was fixed just a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you like me have this issue, but you can't upgrade the compiler nor change the code. A quick fix is to have the compiler remove the asserts by adding the NDEBUG flag to the compiler:

- gcc/clang: `-DNDEBUG`
- msvc: `/DNDEBUG`

Maybe this can save someone a bit of time.