# Handling fatal errors (or asserts) in constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c++17

What should I do in the following function if the argument type T is wrong?

```
    template <class T>
    constexpr inline size_t GetObjectSize(const T & val)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<T>::value)
        {
            return sizeof(val);
        }

        if constexpr (std::is_class<T>)
        {
            return 5u;
        }

        //there should be compile time error.
    }

    int * p;
    //compile time error
    GetObjectSize(p);
```

Possible alternatives are 1) throwing an exception 2) [assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397841/assert-in-constexpr-function) 3) static_assert

1) Exception of what type should I throw?

2) it is implementation defined and is not guaranteed to be a costexpr.

3) static_assert(false) always fails independently of T.

Comment: In this case perhaps specialization is better? And as always, doing `switch` or `if` checks on type is usually an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes,  specialization looks better, because I need specialization for static_assert, see the answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it was not quite correct. static_assert(false) can be used with 'if else if else'.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude static_assert(false) works with MSVC2017, but with GCC it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> static_assert(false) always fails independently of T.

Then make it dependent on `T`.

```
template<typename>
struct always_false { enum {value = 0}; };

// ...

if constexpr(...) {
}
else {
    static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "Some useful description");
}
```

Yes, it's a a magician's trick. But the dry letter of the law is okay with it. Sadly there isn't really a better way to print a useful diagnostic in a dependent branch of an `if constexpr`.

Comment: Are you sure static_assert should be in 'else' branch?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky - Of course. Otherwise it will be a part of *all* branches.

Comment: Moreover, your branches should really be an `if else if else` chain for this to work.

Comment: Yes, static_assert(false) works if there is 'if else if else'. So the answer is static_assert(false).

Comment: in GCC static_assert(false) always fails even with 'if else if else', see https://wandbox.org/permlink/PPlHHK6HlQE3LIJr

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky - Which is why I did not suggest `static_assert(false)`, but to make the condition formally dependent too.