# throw in constexpr function: do we need wrapping condition?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

Basic idea is this: I have some `constexpr` function and I want to use `throw` to signal error and lazy compilation to avoid this error in normal flow:

```
template <size_t N>
auto constexpr find_elt(const std::array<int, N>& a, int k) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    if (k == a[i])
      return i;
  throw "not found";
}
```

And then:

```
constexpr int result = find_elt(arr, 4);
```

Normally, if 4 exists in the array, I will get its index back at compile-time.

If not, I will fall through to `throw` to indicate the lookup is erroneous at compile-time, and the compiler will produce a pretty error.

But I noticed strange behavior:

[Under the latest clang, everything works](https://godbolt.org/z/4fYbAB)

[Under the latest gcc, everything fails](https://godbolt.org/z/6EdqDH)

Is this idea legitimate? Is this code correct for what I want to achieve? Which compiler tells me the truth here?

If not, what is the correct way to do this?

Any links to C++ standard are appreciated. I read through constexpr-related chapters, but I am in doubt.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280729/throw-in-constexpr-function

Comment: @cigien question by your link is about radically simpler case, fixed in gcc 6, over 4 years ago

Comment: I'd guess it's the same idea here, and it's a gcc bug.

Comment: Not clear. In cited case throw is under explicit condition and everything is obvious. In this case may be gcc is correct and I shall rewrite code to put throw under some explicit condition too.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's the same thing. clang will also fail if you pass an argument that causes the function to throw.

Comment: This is by design. If I am looking for something that can not be found I want compile-time failure

Comment: I know. I'm saying that the design is fine, and it's a gcc bug imo.

Comment: Changing the function a little makes gcc happy [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ufi_5E). So probably a gcc bug.

Answer (score 2):

So:

1. according to the fact that the compilation of constexpr functions is a "lazy" process, then the check for compliance with the requirements for a constexpr function is performed only in the scope where the compiler still entered during expression substitution.
2. a function is a scope, respectively - all the rules for constexpr must be observed in the entire body of a function in its first level, scope.
3. and since the expression "throw" is not a constant expression (as the gcc-10 compiler already tells us about it), the correctness is not observed.

The clang compiler is not as strict in this sense as gcc. Therefore, in this battle, in my opinion, gcc wins. He is more committed to the Standard.
On the other hand, if this is a "lazy" process, then why shouldn't it be lazy to the end. Well, you found the final return - so why check the correctness further?
In this sense, clang gets a point.

And in the end - what does the [C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) say?

10.1.5 The constexpr specifier [dcl.constexpr]

5. "... if no argument values ​​exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (8.20), ..., the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Next, let's see what the "core constant expression" is:

8.20 Constant expressions [expr.const]

2. An expression is a the evaluation of, following the rules of the abstract machine (4.6), would evaluate one of the following expressions:

2.22 - a throw-expression (8.17)

And note that "no diagnostic required" and the compiler is not required to provide a detailed explanation of the reason for the failure.